# Checking version after installing Python on Mac gives unexpected results

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I just installed python on my mac and try to run python3 -v in the terminal but get this error.

When I run ptyhon -v, I get "xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools". When i install this command line I get the same error.

When i run python3 -v I get this:

```
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'posix' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__init__.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/aliases.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__pycache__/aliases.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102998310>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10297e9d0>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/utf_8.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/encodings/__pycache__/utf_8.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10297f1d0>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import 'io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_collections_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import 'genericpath' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import 'posixpath' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import 'os' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_sitebuiltins' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
Processing user site-packages
Processing global site-packages
Adding directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages'
Processing .pth file: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc'
import '_distutils_hack' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1029baa10>
import 'site' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# extension module 'readline' loaded from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-311-darwin.so'
# extension module 'readline' executed from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-311-darwin.so'
import 'readline' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x1029ba1d0>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/rlcompleter.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/rlcompleter.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/rlcompleter.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/inspect.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/inspect.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/inspect.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/ast.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ast.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/ast.cpython-311.pyc'
import '_ast' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/contextlib.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/contextlib.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/keyword.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/keyword.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/keyword.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'keyword' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a64c90>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/operator.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/operator.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/operator.cpython-311.pyc'
import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'operator' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a651d0>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/reprlib.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/reprlib.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/reprlib.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'reprlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a65d90>
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'collections' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a38a90>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/functools.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/functools.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/functools.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/types.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/types.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/types.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'types' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a8cad0>
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'functools' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a3b610>
import 'contextlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a2fa90>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/enum.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/enum.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/enum.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'enum' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102a38750>
import 'ast' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1029f3210>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/dis.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/dis.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/dis.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/opcode.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/opcode.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/opcode.cpython-311.pyc'
# extension module '_opcode' loaded from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-311-darwin.so'
# extension module '_opcode' executed from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-311-darwin.so'
import '_opcode' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x102c52250>
import 'opcode' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c46f90>
import 'dis' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1029f9650>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__pycache__/abc.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/abc.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/collections/__pycache__/abc.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'collections.abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c3a8d0>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/warnings.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/warnings.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/warnings.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'warnings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c54290>
import 'importlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c3a710>
import 'importlib.machinery' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/linecache.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/linecache.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/linecache.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/tokenize.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tokenize.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/tokenize.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__init__.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_compiler.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/_compiler.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_compiler.cpython-311.pyc'
import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_parser.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/_parser.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_parser.cpython-311.pyc'
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_constants.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/_constants.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_constants.cpython-311.pyc'
import 're._constants' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c833d0>
import 're._parser' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c80510>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_casefix.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/_casefix.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/re/__pycache__/_casefix.cpython-311.pyc'
import 're._casefix' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c92d50>
import 're._compiler' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c75110>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/copyreg.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/copyreg.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/copyreg.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'copyreg' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c98190>
import 're' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c6b190>
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/token.cpython-311.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/token.py
# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/__pycache__/token.cpython-311.pyc'
import 'token' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c6bc90>
import 'tokenize' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c57fd0>
import 'linecache' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c3a750>
import 'inspect' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1029d1090>
import 'rlcompleter' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1029d0290>
Python 3.11.4 (v3.11.4:d2340ef257, Jun  6 2023, 19:15:51) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: How do you install Python? Using `brew` or image from official site?

Comment: `python -v` **does not** give you the Python version (well, it does, but indirectly). The `-v` flag prints a message each time a module is initialized. You want `python --version`.

Comment: `python -v` provides a verbose import statement trace. Use capital V instead, as `python -V`.

Answer (score 0):

`python -v` does not give you the Python version (well, it does, but indirectly). The `-v` flag prints a message each time a module is initialized. You want `python --version`.

Comment: Yes, or `-V` can be used as well.